# Checking if function uses an if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is there a method or way in JavaScript that I can check if assert if a function returns a value through the use of an `if` statement?

So this:

```
function(val) {
  if (val) return "it is true";
  return "it is false";
}
```

versus this:

```
function(val) {
  var str = 'it is ';
  return str += val;
}
```

I've been looking around and can only find articles related to Java or other languages. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm writing tests to assert whether or not a function (written by a user) utilizes an if statement. Hope that clarifies that a bit!

Comment: My question will be, why do you want to know if a function uses a condition? you can easily set some values if some conditions are met. But why?

Comment: If you need to do this, you're doing it wrong!

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Ibu I made an update to the question. It's for testing code written by someone else. If there's not a method, that's fine. Just wondering.

Comment: @Jose: No, there's no method. You could get the `.toString()` value of the function and use a JavaScript parser to analyse if there's an `if` statement.

Comment: Your use case doesn't make sense either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'd like to mention that such checks shouldn't be used in code, in which I mean that proper code should never check whether an if-statement is used inside a function. Whether a value is returned from it or not, this shouldn't be checked or tested.

---

But, to get back on topic. I'm not quite sure whether this is possible out of the box. I do however have a solution that you might be able to use to achieve something similar to your goals.

You can convert a given function to it's string representation. Take a look at the following example:

```
// Define a function
var myFunction = function() {
    return 1 + 3;
};

// Print the function, as a string
console.log(myFunction.toString());
```

This code will print the string representation of the function in the console, so that will be `function() { return 1 + 3; }`. Some environments, such as the Firefox return a compiled version of the function which would look like `function() { return 4; }` but that doens't really have any effect on our use.

Using this method you'll be able to check whether the given function contains an if-statement. Such code would look like this:

```
// Define a function
var myFunction = function() {
    return 1 + 3;
};

// Check whether the given function contains an if-statement
if(myFunction.toString().indexOf('if') > -1) {
    console.log('This function does contain an if-statement');
} else {
    console.log('This function does not contain an if-statement');
}
```

This method isn't ideal for your situation but it might point you in the right direction. Please note that this method isn't a rock-solid solution, at least not in this state. The usage of 'if' as a string (or something else) in a function would also cause the code above to say that the function contains an if-statement. Also, this doesn't explicitly check whether a value is returned from inside of an if-statement.

If you'd like to ensure the things mentioned above (that a real if-statement is used, in which a value is returned from it) you might have to modify the above code to make it smarter if this string-based method suits your needs. Then, I'd highly recommend to write a fancy wrapper around it to make it easier in use.